# Passing Multiple Password through SSHPASS

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have 3 Linux system.

System_A
System_B
System_C

I want to copy a file from "System_B" to "System_C", while being logged in from system System_A.

Below code copies the file from "System_A" to "System_C" (as I'm running this while logged in from "System A")

```
sshpass -p "pass123" scp /u01/File_A.txt oracle@$ServerIP_C:/u01/File_C.txt
```

Also, below code does what I want.i.e. copies file from "System_B" to "System_C", while being logged in from system System_A.

```
sshpass -p "pass123" scp oracle@$ServerIP_B/u01/File_B.txt oracle@$ServerIP_C:/u01/File_C.txt
```

But in above code it asks for 1 password as I'm only passing 1 password through sshpass instead of 2.

How can I pass the 2nd password through sshpass here so that it doesn't prompt me for password.

I have tried below codes:

```
 sshpass -p "pass123" sshpass -p "pass123" scp oracle@IP_B:/tmp/File_B.txt oracle@IP_C:/tmp/File_C.txt
This throws error: Conflicting password source

sshpass -p "pass123" scp oracle@IP_B:/tmp/File_B.txt sshpass -p "pass123" oracle@IP_C:/tmp/File_C.txt
Promted for 1 Password
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using SSH keys. With a key you can connect to a computer without having to enter a password. It is also recommended as an alternative on the sshpass man page.

Comment: I totally agree with you on key pair, however i have limited access to the changes which i can make to set up Key pair, That is the reason why I want this somehow to work using sshpass.

Comment: You can try to pass two lines as argument to the `-p` option separated by a newline. You can also try to invoke `sshpass` twice, like `sshpass -p "pass1" sshpass -p "pass2" scp ...`.

Comment: Could you please give command for "You can try to pass two lines as argument to the -p option separated by a newline."... The later didn't worked, I have edited the question with output of later command.

Comment: I just looked at the source, it will not work with two passwords, I just looked at the source. But you might try the program `expect`.